# Core Plot - Assigning a CPTGraphHostingView from a class

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, core-plot, viewcontroller

I've been trying to get a dashboard working with various graphs presented using Core Plot. I've managed to get the first to work how I want by including the code in the AppDelegate.m, but this makes it difficult to get a second working and would mean that my AppDelegate becomes huge and difficult to work with if I include them all in the same file.

Is there any way that I can set the CPTGraphHostingView that I want the plot to be contained in from a separate class? Or perhaps I can set a method to do this? This is probably a simple question but any help would be appreciated! I've looked through the examples provided in the SDK and don't seem to be able to work out how it's being done!

This is the code I'm currently using in my AppDelegate method:

```
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
graph = (CPTXYGraph*) [theme newGraph]; 
_graphView.hostedGraph = graph;
```

.... Followed by the specifications for the graph....

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate view controller for each graph to handle the setup. The view controller can also be the datasource and plot delegate (all of the Core Plot examples do this), although those functions could also be handled by another class.

See, for example, the CPTTestApp (Mac version) example app. It has four different controller classes to handle the various demos.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, though the example has three view controllers that each determine the actions of views in three separate windows. Is it the same method for having three CustomViews in the same window?

Comment: Yes—it doesn't matter if the views are in the same or different windows.